# Postfix forwarding to email addresses in /etc/passwd

Tags: postfix, user-accounts, mail-forwarding, passwd

If one maintains a database of emails in /etc/passwd how can Postfix be configured to forward email to those?

Comment: I don't know if /etc/passwd can be used by postfix, but I'm not ruling it out. I'd say /etc/aliases is used. Also ~username/.forward might work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the default configuration Postfix is already configured to deliver mails to all accounts in /etc/passwd and all aliases in /etc/aliases:
http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#local_recipient_maps

Otherwise you can set the local_recipient_maps to the default value.